# Is it possible to convert AppsKey to a modifier key in Debian?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I never use the *<AppsKey>* (or *<Menu>*), and I want to convert it to a modifier key, e.g. Mod4, Mod5, etc. So as to utilize some shortcuts like *<Mod5>+<Shift>+J*.

Is it possible in Debian/Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a free modifier key name such as `Hyper` or `Super` (it must not be used by another key). Also pick a free modifier number amongst `Mod1` to `Mod5`. You can figure out the free ones by looking through the output of `xmodmap -pke -pm`. Also figure out the keycode for the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key. Then add lines like the following to `~/.Xmodmap`:

```
keycode 0x75 = Hyper_R
add Mod4 = Hyper_R
```

If you're not already using a `.Xmodmap` file, add the following line to your X startup script (maybe `~/.xinitrc` or `~/.xsession`; some desktop environments automatically read `~/.Xmodmap` so you won't need this step):

```
xmodmap - <~/.Xmodmap
```

Comment: A little question, which one should I use in best practice, `.xinitrc` or `.xsession` ?

Comment: @谢继雷: it's not a matter of best practice: you have to use `.xinitrc` if you log in in text mode then run `startx`, and you have to use `.xsession` if you log in under *dm. If you use your own session script (which is not as common as it used to be: nowadays most people start a desktop environment which has its own way of running commands when you log in), you can arrange for `.xsession` to contain just `. ~/.profile; . ~/.xinitrc`.